# Max Recursion Depth Error With Grid Search Problem

Tags: recursion

I've written out a potential solution to a Leetcode problem but I get this error involving maximum recursion depth.  I'm really unsure what I'm doing wrong.  Here's what I've tried writing:

```
def orangesRotting(grid):
    R,C = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    seen = set()
    min_time = 0
    
    def fresh_search(r,c, time):
        if ((r,c,time) in seen or r < 0 or c < 0 or r >= R or c >= C or grid[r][c] == 0):
            return
        elif grid[r][c] == 2:
            seen.add((r,c,0))
        elif grid[r][c] == 1:
            seen.add((r,c, time + 1))
        
        fresh_search(r+1,c,time+1)
        fresh_search(r-1,c,time+1)
        fresh_search(r,c+1,time+1)
        fresh_search(r,c-1,time+1)      
    
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            if grid[i][j] == 2:
                fresh_search(i,j,0)
                
    for _,_,t in list(seen):
        min_time = max(min_time,t)
    
    return min_time
```

Even on a simple input like `grid = [[2,1,1], [1,1,0], [0,1,1]]`.  The offending line always appears to be at the if statement

`if ((r,c,time) in seen or r < 0 or c < 0 or r >= R or c >= C or grid[r][c] == 0):`

Please note, I'm not looking for help in solving the problem, just understanding why I'm running into this massive recursion issue.  For reference, here is the [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/) to the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's trace through what you are doing here. You iterate through the entire grid and if the value for that cell is 2 you call `fresh_search` for that cell. We'll start with `[0,0]`

In `fresh_search` you then add the cell with times seen = 0 to your set.

Now for all neighboring cells you call `fresh_search` so we'll just look at `r+1`. For `r+1` your method `fresh_search` adds the cell to your set with times seen = 1 and then calls `fresh_search` again with all neighboring cells.

Next we'll just look at `r-1` which is our origin and now `fresh_search` is being called with this cell and times seen = 2. Now this value isn't in the set yet because `(0,0,0) != (0,0,2)` so it adds it to the set and again calls `fresh_search` with the `r+1` cell but now times seen = 3

and so on and so forth until max recursion.